# Comments markdown parser: bold nested in italic is rendered as plain italic

Tags: bug, comments, markdown, markdown-rendering

Bold nested in italic is rendered as plain italic without the bold markdown being interpreted in comments. See the examples and the comments:

#### Not working

```
_Italic and **bold**_
```

is rendered as *Italic and **bold***. It doesn't interpret the bold markup.

#### Working

```
_Italic and **bold** followed by more italic_
```

is rendered correctly: *Italic and **bold** followed by more italic*

Comment: _Italic and **bold**_

Comment: _Italic and **bold** followed by more italic_

Comment: _Italic and **bold**._ Workaround: `_Italic and **bold**._`

Comment: _Italic and __bold___ or *Italic and **bold***

Comment: @MartijnPieters: _Italic and_ ***bold*** > `_Italic and_ ***bold***` ?

Comment: @Alberto: As far as I know, the whitespace breaking the markdown is by design. Otherwise, _"1 * 2 * 3"_ would get formatted, for example.

Comment: @Cerbrus thanks! In that case, I'll delete the `Case 2b` and edit `Case 2`

Comment: @Cerbrus see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to switch characters; the work-around is to stick with all underscores or all asterisks:

```
 _Italic and __bold___
```

or

```
 *Italic and **bold***
```

Nevertheless, alternating should work as well, so it *is* a bug in the comments markdown parser.

Comment: Expect that to have a big dollop of development resources anytime soon.